# NSView change type of property animation

Tags: cocoa, animation, core-animation, nsview

I have an `NSButton` that I'd like to animate when I call `[button setHidden: NO];`  However, I don't want the default fade animation, I'd like a slide-from-left animation instead.

I'm sure it's not that complicated, but I'm struggling to find the right location in the docs. Any suggestions?

Comment: To be clear, I want to use kCATransitionMoveIn or or kCATransitionReveal instead of kCATransitionFade.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like the correct answer to add a custom animation to the layer, and then just set the property, instead of using the default animator for the property:

```
CATransition *animation = [CATransition animation];
[animation setDuration: 0.2];
[animation setType: kCATransitionMoveIn];
[animation setSubtype: kCATransitionFromRight];
[animation setTimingFunction: [CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName: kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut]];   

[[button layer] addAnimation: animation forKey: @"slidebutton"];
[button setHidden: NO];
```

Still not 100% clear what the difference is on Mac OS X between `kCATransitionFade` and `kCATransitionReveal`.

Answer (score 1):

You should change the frame *via* the animator proxy.

```
NSRect aFrameMoreToTheLeft = …;
[[button animator] setFrame:aFrameMoreToTheLeft];
```